# Why can Shazam fly?

Tags: plot-explanation, dc-extended-universe, shazam

When Billy Batson is gifted the powers of Shazam, the Wizard claims

> Yes. I give you the power. And with it all my strength. Solomon's wisdom. The power of Hercules. Atlas toughness. The power of Zeus. The courage of Achilles. And Mercury's speed.

None of these mythical characters fly, but Shazam can. **What gives him the power of flight?** Was that part of the Wizard's original powers? Or why wasn't a flying mythical entity referred to in this line of dialogue?

Comment: `Solomon's wisdom`...In the film, he wasn't shown as being particularly wise. I'd just take the whole quote as more symbolic and not literally related to his power set. At least in terms of this movie's interpretation of the character

Comment: I would say that the title is a spoiler. I haven't seen Shazam yet and the trailer actually seemed to suggest that he wasn't able to fly.

Comment: @IvoBeckers This [one](https://youtu.be/uilJZZ_iVwY?t=23) shows flight, but I'll edit

Comment: ah, my bad. I only saw the first trailer

Comment: @Wmbuch He also wasn't shown as being particularly good at flying, until he got the hang of it.  I think we can safely interpret his actions at the end of the film as evidence that he'd gotten the hang of tapping into Solomon's wisdom as well as he had done with the other powers.

Comment: I would say a spoiler considerably alters the movie watching experience negatively - knowing a particular character, a superhero, possesses a specific power, shouldn't spoil a movie, but I recognize that's just my opinion. I liked the original title

Comment: Since this is set in the same universe as __[Wonder Woman](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0451279/)__ it coud be part of __Zeus__' power set, because at the end of "Wonder Woman" we see Ares fly, and Diana (a demi-god and daughter of Zeus) was, at the very least, floating in the air. So it stands to reason that Zeus is also capable of flight. But I'm just guessing here.

Comment: Why flying is so big deal O.o

Comment: Out of DCEU, Shazam is a copy of Superman, he has to show basically the same power.

Comment: When you ask a question like that, a wizard did it.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Hermes/Mercury is well known for his winged shoes, also known as [Talaria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talaria)

According to wikipedia(citation needed), they **flew** the god as swift as any bird.
So I would say that even if it not explicitely stated, Flying falls under Mercury Powers.

Comment: I hadn't realized that, [Mercury](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury_(mythology))'s page didn't say anything about flight, and I didn't search for *wings*. +1

Comment: Huh, I'd read stories with the character in for years and never spotted the links to the mythological figures spelling SHAZAM

Comment: Do they explicitly explain the acronym in the movie or are you left to put that together on your own?

Comment: @JPhi1618 See the quote in the question. I don't think the connection to the acronym is ever explicitly stated though.

Comment: The acronym was explained in the older comics, though not often.

Comment: @DoctorPenguin, The acronym things is a constant in SHAZAM. For exemple Black Adam also got it's power from divinity and it's also spell "SHAZAM", but from egypthian god : Shu, Haru, Amon, Zehuti, Aton, Mehen.

Comment: In more modern comics he's often directly facing the god he got power from. And the letter are always part of the dialog https://static.comicvine.com/uploads/original/11127/111270529/5558112-8495661619-shaza.jpg